# im trying to plot some oscillating data by python keeps changing it to a linear line?

Tags: python, plot

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x, y = np.loadtxt(r'C:/Users/ibrah/OneDrive/Documents/s1 oscillation masses.txt', delimiter=',', unpack=True, usecols = (0,1))

print(x,y)

plt.plot(x,y, '*', markersize=4)
```

Data plotted using code above:

[image]

here's the same data but plotted with excel directly:

[image]

Comment: Could you include the head of your text file? It could be an import issue. Maybe it's plotting the number of the row instead of the actual x axis?

Comment: My text file only contains my data with no header. I tried using usecols to see if it was doing that but going above 1 column gives an out of range error. It was working a couple of hours ago but suddenly it doesnt. ive try loading with pandas and it seems to work but i dont know how to separate the data into x and y using it so i gave up.

Comment: I mean head, not header, like the first 10 lines. Also, with pandas, you could do something like `df = pd.read_csv(<your file>, delimiter=',', sep=<your separator, tab, space, etc>)`

Comment: i dont get the sep arg. Can i then use the x and y columns separately?

Comment: data = pandas.read.csv(r'C:/Users/ibrah/OneDrive/Documents/s1 oscillation with masses.txt', delimiter=',', sep = <x, y>)                                                             something like this?

Comment: y seems to be x somehow, so I suspect the loading method loadtxt may not return y at all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the tuple unpacking is not working as expected i.e. you are plotting the y value for both the x and y value.

Check your data file to see that your file definitely uses a delimeter ‘,’ between the x and y values.

Also put an example of your data file in your question so we can see what is in that file.

Comment: 32,4.4
32.25,3.8
32.5,4.4
32.75,5.7
33,7.6
33.25,10.2
33.5,14.7
33.75,17.9
34,21.7
34.25,26.8
34.5,31.3
34.75,36.4
35,40.9
35.25,46
35.5,50.5
35.75,55
36,58.8
36.25,62
36.5,65.2
36.75,67.2
37,69.1
37.25,69.7
37.5,70.4
37.75,70.4
38,69.1
38.25,67.8
38.5,66.5
38.75,64
39,60.1
39.25,56.9
39.5,53.7
39.75,49.9
40,46
heres some of my data from the file copy and pasted

Comment: It a new line every 2 numbers in the actual file

Comment: What does the print statement output?

Comment: When i print the x and y separately it outputs the correct numbers. Its only when i plot it changes everything to a linear plot.

Comment: Try using ‘data = np.loadtxt(....)’ and get rid of the usecols. Then to plot use plt.plot(data[0], data[1], ‘*’,markersize=4). Look at this https://likegeeks.com/numpy-loadtxt-tutorial/ and look at the second example

Comment: thats still giving the same problem im afraid. It might be easier to just use pandas. Do you know how i can separate the x and y columns when i do pd.read_csv?

Comment: Yes if your data has headers then you can do data[‘X’] and data[‘Y’].

Comment: Ok same problem when i separate using pandas but works when i just plot data as a whole. I have no idea what's happening

Comment: So is it working now but when you plot data?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i seem to have fixed it. It appears to have been an issue with the way i changed the delimiter of the data after copying it from the excel file. I tried using a program on the internet instead and for some reason that worked.